# Why does my phone's RFID UID change each time I scan it on a RFID scanning system?

Tags: arduino, rfid

I am currently playing around with RFID on my Arduino UNO using RC522 module. I have followed a code tutorial from this website https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-rfid-nfc and am able to get a UID reading from RFID tags that came with the bundle which stay the same each time I scan them as should be expected as seen below.

[image: RFID Tag Result]

Out of curiosity, I have been scanning various objects that contain an RFID tag and when placing my phone at the sensor the UID changes each time.

[image: Phone RFID Tag Result]

Could somebody explain why this is the case? I presume this has something to do encryption and or security as when I try scanning a bank card this does not occur.

Answer (score 2):

The UID on a cell phone is normally dynamic and changes each time the phone is read.

See:

> Usually, a new UID is generated for each NFC transaction by phones. Some users have been able to maintain a static UID sent from the phone to the RFID receiver. A static UID will then act to send a constant "key" across to the RFID receiver instead of a generated one, everytime you try to swipe the device. -- https://superuser.com/questions/653279/possible-to-playback-rfid-card-using-nfc-functionality-on-phone